# Eclipse JDT ASTRewrite

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am following a tutorial on how to add a comment to a .java file. I would like to know how to specify a specific line number for the insertion, if that's possible.

```
    /*Determines the insertion point*/
    TypeDeclaration typeDecl = (TypeDeclaration) astRoot.types().get(0);
    MethodDeclaration methodDecl = typeDecl.getMethods()[0];
    Block block = methodDecl.getBody();

    /*Inserts comment*/
    ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(block, Block.STATEMENTS_PROPERTY);
    Statement placeHolder = (Statement) rewriter.createStringPlaceholder("//mycomment", ASTNode.EMPTY_STATEMENT);
    listRewrite.insertFirst(placeHolder, null);
```

If you could perhaps direct me to a tutorial or provide a short snippet of code, it will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The abstract syntax tree represents the program in a hierarchical format. Therefore the layout and formatting information is not relevant. Afaik this is also true for Eclipse implementation of the AST, which means, you cannot access the line number or indention of a certain statement or element in the syntax tree.

Comment: Hmmmm, thank you for your reply. I was hoping I would somehow be able to identify the line numbers. I was afraid that this won't be possible.